# Why can't I make a Table row using JavaScript and a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

For some reason the following piece of code does not work to insert an extra table into my `html` document. The text is just randomly sitting at the top of the table instead of IN the table. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function insertTable() {

    var table = document.getElementById("houseListingTable").innerHTML;
    table = table + "<tr><td>58,500</td><td>Montreal</td></tr>";
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
    <div id = "houseListingTable">
    </div>
</table>

<button onclick = "insertTable()">Insert Table<\button>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the table row add itself to my table when I click on the `Insert Table` button? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: that is invalid html, divs are not supposed to be direct children of table tags, and tr's arent supposed to be direct children of div tags

Comment: @PatrickEvans Is that why it is not working then? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Having a `<div>` element directly inside a `<table>` is invalid HTML.
- Your `table` variable here is just a string. Overwriting it has no effect on the DOM.

To fix it:

1. Remove the `<div>` and give the `<table>` an ID:

```
<table id="houseListingTable">
<tr>
    <th>Price<\th>
    <th>Location<\th>
</tr>
</table>
```

2. Use this JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("houseListingTable");
table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>58,500</td><td>Montreal</td></tr>";
```

Note how I am actually overwriting the table's `.innerHTML` property. This is an important distinction from what you have there.

Comment: Awesome! This solves my problem. Thanks for a clear and straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of comments before the answer. Please note that you are missing the html tag at the begging, and that you are using the incorrect bar "\" to close tags in table headers (it should be < /th>) and in the button tag (< /button>).

Also, the div inside the table is not correct.

The code does nothing because the function just gets the innerHTML. For your purpose, the function should get what's inside the table, add a row and then paste it back on the table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function insertTable() {
            var table = document.getElementById("houseListingTable").innerHTML;
            table = table + "<tr><td>58,500</td><td>Montreal</td></tr>";
            document.getElementById("houseListingTable").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="houseListingTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick = "insertTable()">Insert Table</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using a tablet to type up the code. I actually code on desktop but I ask on my tablet. I'll keep that in mind for future questions tho.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken. The ending tags are wrong.

```
<table id="houseListingTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use the **insertRow** of DOM method to add rows to table by getting the table first by Id

```
function insertTable() {

          // Find a <table> element with id="houseListingTable":
        var table = document.getElementById("houseListingTable");

        // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the table:
       var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);


        // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        // Append a text node to the cell1
        var price  = document.createTextNode('58,500')
        cell1.appendChild(price);

        // Append a text node to the cell2
        var location  = document.createTextNode('Montreal')
        cell2.appendChild(location);
        }
```